# Clustering and classification

Tags: classification, cluster-analysis

I need to perform clustering and classification on data, which is present in a csv file. The data is in form of simple text containing the vendor names.

Is there some free library available for this task?

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: https://www.r-project.org

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "clustering a classification" since those two are different from each other, but you can do clustering and classification with these libraries:

[Python-Scikit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/)

[Java-weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)

Answer (score 0):

First convert your Dataset from csv to arff using the following link.

http://www.cs.ccsu.edu/~markov/MDLclustering/MDLmanual.pdf

After doing this please let me know that what are your expectations from the data as every algorithm in weka show some different results.

You can simply apply k-means and any other algorithm once you convert the data.